# Save Multiple Rows from table to Backend SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm having issues with saving multiple rows to the back-end. I don't know how to send all the rows in batch, so I was trying to send each row at a time but it hits  after it has put the last row into the oEntry.

```
submitButtonPress: function() {
var oModel = this.getModel();
var hasChanges = oModel.hasPendingChanges();

if (hasChanges) {
    var mcJson = {};
            //get only rows with changes
    var modelChanges = oModel.getPendingChanges();
    mcJson = modelChanges;

    var mcJsonLength = Object.keys(mcJson).length;
    var mcJsonKey = Object.keys(mcJson);
    var officeCode = this.byId("officeCombo").getValue();
    var oEntry = {};

   //for each row get data
for (var i = 0; i < mcJsonLength; i++) {
    var item = mcJsonKey[i];
    var obj = modelChanges[item];
    var estDate = this.convertDate(obj.ESTIMATE_DATE);

            oEntry.MRU_ID = obj.EST_MRU_ID.toString();
    oEntry.ESTIMATE_PRCT = obj.ESTIMATE_PRCT;
    oEntry.INSTALL_READ = obj.INSTALL_READ;
    oEntry.PLAN_ESTIMATE = obj.EST_INSTALL;
    oEntry.MRU_DATE = estDate;
    oEntry.OFFICE_CODE = officeCode.toString();*/


oModel.create("/MRU_ESTSet", oEntry, {
    success: function(oData, response) {
       sap.m.MessageBox.alert("MRU: " + oEntry.MRU_ID + " EST DATE:" + oEntry.MRU_DATE + " SAVED!");},
error: function(oError) {
    sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error Saving Entries!!");
}
});

}
} else {
sap.m.MessageBox.alert("No Changes To Submit");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oDataModel V2 then what you could just simply do is:

```
oModel.submitChanges()
```

This would send all changes made to the model in a batch.

[submitChanges method documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/submitChanges)

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me.
Adding:

```
oModel.setUseBatch(true);

oModel.create("/MRU_ESTSet", oEntry, {
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function(oData) {
                        //sap.m.MessageBox.alert("success sent!");
                    },
                    error: function(oError) {
                        //sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error Saving Entries!!");
                    }
                });
            }

            oModel.submitChanges({
                success: function(oData, response) {
                    sap.m.MessageBox.success("Success Saving Entries!");
                },
                error: function(oError) {
                    sap.m.MessageBox.error("Error Saving Entries!!");
                }
            });
```

So the function ends up like this and only sends one confirmation instead of many:

```
submitButtonPress: function() {
        var oModel = this.getModel();
        oModel.setUseBatch(true);
        var hasChanges = oModel.hasPendingChanges();

        if (hasChanges) {
            var mcJson = {};
            var modelChanges = oModel.getPendingChanges();
            mcJson = modelChanges;

            var mcJsonLength = Object.keys(mcJson).length;
            var mcJsonKey = Object.keys(mcJson);
            var officeCode = this.byId("officeCombo").getValue();

            for (var i = 0; i < mcJsonLength; i++) {
                var item = mcJsonKey[i];
                var obj = modelChanges[item];
                var estDate = this.convertDate(obj.ESTIMATE_DATE);

                var oEntry = {
                    MRU_ID: obj.EST_MRU_ID,
                    ESTIMATE_PRCT: obj.ESTIMATE_PRCT,
                    INSTALL_READ: obj.INSTALL_READ,
                    PLAN_ESTIMATE: obj.EST_INSTALL,
                    MRU_DATE: estDate,
                    OFFICE_CODE: officeCode
                };

                oModel.create("/MRU_ESTSet", oEntry, {
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function(oData) {
                        //sap.m.MessageBox.alert("success sent!");
                    },
                    error: function(oError) {
                        //sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error Saving Entries!!");
                    }
                });
            }

            oModel.submitChanges({
                success: function(oData, response) {
                    sap.m.MessageBox.success("Success Saving Entries!");
                },
                error: function(oError) {
                    sap.m.MessageBox.error("Error Saving Entries!!");
                }
            });

        } else {
            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("No Changes To Submit");
        }
    },
```